# PHP: Compare an array against a string (or an array) and add to that string?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

> I am fairly new to php so I am not sure of the names and terms of what
>   I would like to find out here. I did do a search on SE but although
>   the titles of questions are similar, they ask a completely different
>   thing which are unfortunately not partially related even. Excuse me in
>   advance if it exists and I could not find.

I have a string `$str= 'somevalue';` or an `$array = ['s', 'o', 'm' ..];`

Now, I have an other array which is 2 dimensional, of which 1st items I want to check against this main array and depending on whether they exist or not, add the 2nd item.

```
$to_match[] = ('match' => 'rnd_letter', 'if_not_add' => 'someval');
$to_match[] = ('match' => 'rnd_letter', 'if_not_add' => 'someval_x');
..
```

rnd_letter is a letter or combination of letters and someval is the same.

How can I check if letter(s) in 'match' exists in $str, and if not, add to the end letters of 'if_not_add' of the array?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$to_match = array();
$to_match[] = array('match' => 'hello', 'if_not_add' => 'value 1');
$to_match[] = array('match' => 'abc', 'if_not_add' => 'value 2');
$to_match[] = array('match' => 'w', 'if_not_add' => 'value 3');

$str = 'Hello World!';
$new_array = array();

foreach($to_match as $value) {
  if(!stristr($str, $value['match'])) {
    $new_array[] = $value['if_not_add'];
  }
}

var_dump($new_array); // outputs array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "value 2" }
```

This will iterate over each array element, then check if the value of `match` exists in `$str`, if not it will add it to `$new_array` (I think that's what you were looking for?)

Comment: Wow! This is such a simple and elegant solution! Thank you very much deifwud. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

String:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen($to_match['match']); i++) {
    $char = substr($to_match['match'], i, 1);
    if (strpos($str, $char) !== false) {
        //contains the character
    } else {
        //does not contain the character
    }
}
```

Array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < strlen($to_match['match']); i++) {
    $char = substr($to_match['match'], i, 1);
    $charFound = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < count($array); j++) {
        if ($char == $array[j]) {
            $charFound = true;
        }
    }

    if ($charFound) {
        //it contains the char
    } else {
        //it doesnt contain the char
    }
}
```

It should be something like this i suppose. Let me know what you think of this.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is impressive but I believe the answer above is a bit more simpler.

Answer (score 1):

you can check whether a string is existed in an array using following way

```
<?php 
$array = array('mike','sam','david','somevalue');
$str = 'somevalue';
if(in_array($str,$array)){
    //do whatever you want to do
    echo $str;
}

?>
```